# Hive multiple CTEs in view

Tags: sql, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Does Hive support multiple CTEs inside VIEW statement? I know Hive supports CTE (HIVE-1180), but not sure if it has any limitation - for example, supporting multiple CTEs inside VIEW statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW prdviews.temp
AS WITH set1 AS (SELECT 1 AS id FROM testdb.table1), 
        set2 AS (select 2 AS id FROM testdb.table2)
SELECT * FROM set1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM set2;

select * from prdviews.temp;
```

Executing above query creates Hive view successfully. But when I run a SELECT query, it returns error. Or am I doing it wrong? The above query or any similar query returns error similar to this:

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException Line 3:24 Table not found 'set1' in definition of VIEW temp [ WITH set1 AS (SELECT 1 AS `id` FROM `testdb`.`table1`), set2 AS (select 2 AS `id` FROM `testdb`.`table2`) SELECT `set1`.`id` FROM set1 UNION ALL SELECT `set2`.`id` FROM set2 ] used as temp at Line 1:14
```

Comment: The issue is with the `UNION ALL`

Comment: I am facing similar issue, did any one find resolution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The below is working in CDH 5x

```
with t1 as(select * from empinfo where empid=101),t2 as(select * from empinfo where empid=102) select * from t1 union all select * from t2;
```

And also the below

```
select * from empinfo where empid=101 union all select * from empinfo where empid=102;
```